# How to get that result without for loop (python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of tuples(`rule`) and a pandas dataframe(`proof_path`) .

**Inputs**

rule :

```
 [('#1', 'X', 'Y'), ('#2', 'X', 'Z'), ('#3', 'Z', 'Y')]
```

proof_path :

```
            p1     X    Y            p2        Z           p3
0  nationality  BART  USA  placeOfBirth  NEWYORK    locatedIn
1  nationality  BART  USA     hasFather   HOMMER  nationality
```

I want to get the following result through input like above.

**result**

```
[[('#1', 'nationality'), ('#2', 'placeOfBirth'), ('#3', 'locatedIn')], 
 [('#1', 'nationality'), ('#2', 'hasFather'), ('#3', 'nationality')]]
```

`#1`, `#2`, and `#3` are bound by values corresponding to `p1`, `p2`, and `p3` columns, respectively, to produce tuples.
These tuples become components of the list, and perform these processes across all rows in the dataframe to obtain the above results.

Please let me know the Python code to perform the above process without for loop.

**Edits**

Here is my code below.

```
relation_group = []
for row in proof_path.itertuples(index=False):
    tmp_path = []
    for depth in range(len(rule)):
        tmp_path.append((rule[depth][0], getattr(row, 'p'+rule[depth][0][1])))
    relation_group.append(tmp_path)
```

Comment: You cannot solve this problem without a `for` loop. At least you will need list comprehension to process the list of rules. What exactly are you trying to accomplish and what have you tried? Show us you code _with_ loops and tell which of them you would like to eliminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as close as you can get to avoiding the loops. But this code uses implicit loops: list comprehension and `zip`.

```
proof_path[[r[0].replace('#','p') for r in rule]]\
           .apply(lambda x: list(zip([r[0] for r in rule], x))).values.tolist()
#[[('#1', 'nationality'), ('#1', 'placeOfBirth'), ('#1', 'locatedIn')], 
# [('#2', 'nationality'), ('#2', 'hasFather'), ('#2', 'nationality')]]
```

Also, calling `.apply` is expensive.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
I added the code underneath and wanted to remove the second for loop.
But your code helped a lot.
Thank you